# Error when recompiling themes from bootswatch using compass

Tags: compass-sass, compass, bootswatch

I'm trying to reproduce the css files of **[bootswatch](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch)** using compass but I receive error.
My compass folders:

```
<project>
   |_ css
   |  |_ styles.css
   |  |_ ..........
   |_ fonts
   |   |_ bootstrap
   |_ img
   |_ js
   |_ sass
      |_ bootstrap
      |   |_ mixins
      |   |_ _variables.scss
      |   |_ .........
      |_ themes
          |_ _cerulean-bootswatch.scss
          |_ _cerulean-variables.scss
      |_ _bootstrap.scss
      |_ _custom-variables.scss
      |_ styles.scss
```

Compass uses last file `styles.scss` to produce `styles.css`.
I created a folder `themes` and copied there the `cerulean` files: `_cerulean-bootswatch.scss` and `_cerulean-variables.scss`. I used the [project](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch) files where all bootswatch themes reside.

Now, I follow the directions of the projects page:

SASS:

```
@import "bootswatch/theme/variables";
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "bootswatch/theme/bootswatch";
```

with my structure these would be:

1. import the theme variables (`_cerulean-variables.scss`)
2. import the bootstrap partial (`_bootstrap.scss`)
3. last import the relevant bootswatch partial (`_cerulean-bootswatch.scss`)

All the above happen at `styles.scss`:

```
// Import custom Bootstrap variables
// Bootswatch theme variables
//@import "themes/cerulean-variables"

// Import Bootstrap for Sass
@import "bootstrap";

// Bootswatch themes
@import "themes/cerulean-bootswatch"
```

If I un-comment `/@import "themes/cerulean-variables"` I receive error:

```
error sass/styles.scss (Line 29: Invalid CSS after "...tstrap for Sass": expected selector or at-rule, was "@import "bootst...")
```

and the `styles.css` contains the error:

```
"Error: Invalid CSS after \"...tstrap for Sass\": expected selector or at-rule, was \"@import \"bootst...\"\A         on line 15 of bs-compass-simple/sass/styles.scss\A \A 10: // Bootswatch theme variables\A 11: @import \"themes/cerulean-variables\"\A 12: \A 13: \A 14: // Import Bootstrap for Sass\A 15: @import \"bootstrap\";\A 16: \A 17: // Bootswatch themes\A 18: @import \"themes/cerulean-bootswatch\"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed out two semi-colons. Should be:

```
// Import custom Bootstrap variables
// Bootswatch theme variables
//@import "themes/cerulean-variables";

// Import Bootstrap for Sass
@import "bootstrap";

// Bootswatch themes
@import "themes/cerulean-bootswatch";
```

Either that or you might need:

```
// Import custom Bootstrap variables
// Bootswatch theme variables
//@import "themes/cerulean-variables"

// Import Bootstrap for Sass
@import "bootstrap"

// Bootswatch themes
@import "themes/cerulean-bootswatch"
```

If Compass uses a different syntax than I'm used to with vanilla SCSS or you've set something to a non-standard configuration. Either way usage should be consistent. I'd suggest likely the former, since the lack of semi-colon would cause an error at @import "bootstrap" when the browser attempted to parse both of the lines together, instead of separately.

Comment: The old missing a semi colon error! One of the originals we've all encountered! Glad to be of help :).